# Dynamically call correct correct setter method with Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I'm working with a library that I cannot modify, which has a class with the following `Enum` and setters.

```
public class MyClass {
  public enum MyEnum {
    ClassA,
    ClassB,
    ClassC
    ...
  }

  private SomeEnum myEnum;
  private Interface ifc; // parent of ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, etc.

  public ClassA setClassA(ClassA classA) {
    ifc = classA;
    myEnum= SomeEnum.ClassA;
  }
  public ClassB setClassB(ClassB classB) {
    ifc = classB;
    myEnum= SomeEnum.ClassB;
  }
  public ClassC setClassC(ClassC classC) {
    ifc = classC;
    myEnum= SomeEnum.ClassC;
  }
  // ... more of these setters 
}
```

Notice how each `Enum` name is a string literal match of a corresponding class name which implements `Interface`, and how each class name has its own specific setter.

The code calling this is otherwise straightforward, as you would imagine:

```
Interface ifc = someCallToGetAnImpl();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); 
myClass.set???(ifc);
```

There are a *lot* of implementations of `Interface`, and I cannot guarantee that a future release of the library will not add more. So I am looking to create a function that can dynamically derive and call the correct setter.

I could, of course, build a big old `if... else if...` block, but that would require a software change when new implementations of `Interface` are built. I'd also considered looking into using [`Class.getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) by building the `name` argument using something like

```
"set" + ifc.getClass.getSimpleName()...
```

That *should* keep the software dynamic, but seems kludgy.

Any clean, production-quality suggestions or approaches would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you're considering, using Reflection via methods like [Class.getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) is the correct approach to take to solve the problem you're describing. It's a kludgy problem, and it merits a kludgy approach.

One thing I would add, though, is that you write unit tests to validate your assumptions about the patterns in that class, so that if they add a method that doesn't follow the pattern, you get alerted to it. For example, what if a new enum value gets added, but there's no method to support it? You'll want to be automatically alerted to something like that.

Comment: Good points. I think I'd also run into a problem if, say, ClassA was extended and the child was passed in. That would break the reflection since I'd be be building a method name that is of the concrete child of ClassA.  Not sure how I can get around that without more reflection to walk up the class hierarchy until I (hopefully) find a matching method? Yuck.

Comment: Yup. Lots of reflection. Unit test the crap out of it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Write an Adapter

Using the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) you can wrap the unmodifiable API of `MyClass` which you don't like and provide a cleaner API to consumers. You can't modify the library so the adapter will live in your codebase.

When I `doSomethingStraightForward` I'm not concerned about the intricate details of how to call `MyClass` I just want set the `Interface` on it. The concern of doing the real interaction with `MyClass` can be hidden.

For example:

```
void doSomethingStraightForward() {
    Interface ifc = someCallToGetAnImpl();
    MyClassInterfaceAdapter myClassAdapter = new MyClassInterfaceAdapter();
    myClassAdapter.setInterface(ifc);
}
```

### Example Implementation

As has been mentioned using reflection you can get at the setters. Here's some code from my attempt at an implementation of a `MyClassInterfaceAdapter`.

```
public MyClassInterfaceAdapter() {
    this.myClass = new MyClass();
    this.interfaceSetters = getSetterMap(myClass);
}

public void setInterface(Interface iface) throws Exception {
    if (iface == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("iface must not be null");
    }

    Class<? extends Interface> ifaceClass = iface.getClass();

    if (!interfaceSetters.containsKey(ifaceClass)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("iface type %s is not supported", ifaceClass.getName()));
    }

    Method ifaceSetter = interfaceSetters.get(ifaceClass);
    ifaceSetter.invoke(myClass, iface);
}

private static Map<Class<? extends Interface>, Method> getSetterMap(MyClass myClass) {
    Map<Class<? extends Interface>, Method> setterMap = new HashMap<>();

    Class<MyClass> myClassType = (Class<MyClass>) myClass.getClass();
    Class<Interface> interfaceType = Interface.class;

    for (Method method : myClassType.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        final String methodName = method.getName();

        if (methodName.startsWith(SetterPrefix)
                && method.getParameterCount() == 1
                && interfaceType.isAssignableFrom(method.getParameterTypes()[0])) {
            try {
                getMatchingMyEnum(method);
                setterMap.put((Class<? extends Interface>) method.getParameterTypes()[0], method);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Setter not compatible: " + methodName, e);
            }
        }
    }

    return setterMap;
}

private static MyEnum getMatchingMyEnum(Method m) {
    int MyEnumStartIndex = SetterPrefix.length();
    String enumName = m.getName().substring(MyEnumStartIndex);
    return Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, enumName);
}
```

### Production Readiness

In terms of using it in production, I'd be thinking of the following:

- You'd want very high test coverage with unit, integration and E2E tests. Tests should cover both happy path and failure scenarios.
- You'd need to think about what you want to do when setting the `Interface` fails. `throws Exception` everywhere is not best practise.
- You might want to manage the creation of `MyClass` and its adapter by factories or an IoC container to make the code more unit testable (similar concept to what we did above, move the concern of creating objects and their dependencies somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

If you have callers that work at the `Interface` level, without caring/knowing which class is actually implementing the interface, don't make that their problem. Implement a `setInterface(Interface)` method.

Don't know why you want/need the `Enum`. Isn't `ifc.getClass()` good enough? It will return the `Class<?>` object, albeit the leaf class, if subclassing is deep.

To make sure you select `Enum ClassA` whenever a `ClassA` or one of it's subclasses are passed, do the following.

```
package test;

interface Interface { /*content not included*/ }

class ClassA implements Interface { /*content not included*/ }
class ClassB implements Interface { /*content not included*/ }
class ClassC implements Interface { /*content not included*/ }

class MyClass {

    public enum MyEnum {
        ClassA(test.ClassA.class),
        ClassB(test.ClassB.class),
        ClassC(test.ClassC.class);

        private final Class<? extends Interface> impl;

        private MyEnum(Class<? extends Interface> impl) {
            this.impl = impl;
        }

        Class<? extends Interface> getImpl() {
            return this.impl;
        }
    }

    private MyEnum    myEnum;
    private Interface ifc;

    public void setInterface(Interface ifc) {
        for (MyEnum e : MyEnum.values()) {
            if (e.getImpl().isAssignableFrom(ifc.getClass())) {
                this.myEnum = e;
                this.ifc = ifc;
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Interface class is unknown: " + ifc.getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

Now the caller has it easy:

```
Interface ifc = someCallToGetAnImpl();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); 
myClass.setInterface(ifc);
```

**Note:** If you have enums for classes that are subclasses of each other, make sure the subclass is listed first. E.g. if `class ClassB extends ClassA`, then `enum ClassB` must be listed before `enum ClassA`.

Comment: I stated that I cannot modify the class. The enum  serves a purpose elsewhere, and yes I agree that it probably could be supplanted by Class objects

Comment: I missed that part. You question is confusing, since you called it `MyClass`, implying that it's yours and you can change it.

Comment: It was the first sentence lol. :) but duly noted for future questions.

Answer (score -2):

Its not possible to dynamically add elements in Enum class by using reflection.
Possibly  you can have a dynamic code to call the method. There is non way to alter enumclass.

There is another way of implementation you can have a xml/properties file where you can configure you enum class dynamically as stated in https://dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-dynamic-enums

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Im not modifying anything in MyClass.